# How to transfer data that are stored in TextView in an activity for calculation in another activity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my DisplayBooks class:

```
public class DisplayBooks extends AppCompatActivity

private FirebaseAuth myAuth;
private DatabaseReference myDatabase;
private TextView book1display,book2display,book3display,book4display,book5display,book6display,book7display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_books);

    myAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    book1display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book1display);
    book2display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book2display);
    book3display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book3display);
    book4display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book4display);
    book5display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book5display);
    book6display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book6display);
    book7display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book7display);


    String user_id = myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference userid_database = myDatabase.child(user_id);

    DatabaseReference book1 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 1").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book2 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 2").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book3 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 3").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book4 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 4").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book5 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 5").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book6 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 6").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book7 = userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 7").child("Page");


    book1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book1display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book2display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book3display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book4.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book4display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book5.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book5display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book6.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book6display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    book7.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            book7display.setText(text);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}


}
```

Below is an example output. I want to get the numbers that in the picture for make a calculation in the another activity.

[image]

This is my other activity:

```
public class HowMuch extends AppCompatActivity


private TextView howmuch1,howmuch2;
TextView hay;
Button button2;
private DatabaseReference myDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth myAuth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_how_much);

    myAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    myDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    howmuch1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.howmuch1);
    howmuch2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.howmuch2);

    hay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hay);

    String user_id= myAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference userid_database=myDatabase.child(user_id);

    DatabaseReference book1=userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 1").child("Page");
    DatabaseReference book2=userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 2").child("Page");


    book1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            String text= dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            int value=Integer.parseInt(text);
            int value1=value/2;

            String x= String.valueOf(value1);

            howmuch1.setText(x);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

If I write like that for book2, book3 etc. I can make calculattion but I also want to make sum of these values. Hovewer, I couldn't transfer values of them to make new calculation. I tried to transfer values from my DisplayBooks activity writing this:

```
public void transfer(View view){
String value = book1display.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayBooks.this, HowMuch.class);
intent.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

And adding this to HowMuch class:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
hay.setText(value);
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You have to create `ArrayList<DatabaseReference>`  and  pass into intent.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
hay.setText(value);
```

Edit: links for reference:

Send data
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Receive data https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: It didn't work. It said "Cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String)' "

Comment: I hope you tried with the book1display textView because that is the textView whose value you are sending to the other activity in your 'transfer' method.

Comment: I am sorry, it should be getStringExtra(), changing now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle receivedBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (receivedBundle != null) {
    String extraString = receivedBundle.getString("key");
    int extraInt = receivedBundle.getInt("key");
}
```

Comment: This will not work because you see the OP is not setting the key-value pair in the bundle. Instead, the key-value pair is added directly into the intent.